# How can we use data-inline="true" for the button type?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, markup, jquery-mobile-button

Could anyone please tell me how can I use `data-inline="true"` to the button type in JQuery mobile ?

eg:  `<button type="submit" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Save</button>`

When I tried it's not working and it's working only for the anchor tag.

eg: `<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Save</a>`

Comment: data-inline="true" is used to create compact button

Comment: @amrit_neo Nope `data-mini="true"` is  used to create compact button.

Comment: data-mini is for small buttons, not compact, there is difference in both

Comment: Check if any custom css is not implementing on buttons or check the jquery and css external files path...

Comment: so is it unable to for this example http://jsfiddle.net/frm683/ewaBd/

Comment: You never accept answers do you? went through some of your old questions. Do accept answers in future if its working for you.

Comment: Actually I do check my profile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with a grid, but that solution don't look nice bacause there's always a big gap between input box and the button.

Then there's an another way, with a little css we can change everything to look more fluid:

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/cbWHm/

**HTML :**

```
<!-- FIRST SOLUTION -->

<div id="hidden-wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="name" data-inline="true" id="basic" value=""  /> 
    <button type="reset" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Reset</button>
</div>

<!-- SECOND SOLUTION -->

<div id="hidden-wrapper2">
    <div id="text-container">
        <input type="text" name="name" data-inline="true" id="basic" value=""  /> 
    </div>
    <div id="btn-container">
        <button type="reset" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Reset</button>
    </div>        
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
/* FIRST SOLUTION */
#hidden-wrapper .ui-input-text {
   width: 68% !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
}

#hidden-wrapper .ui-btn {
   width: 19% !important;
}

/* SECOND SOLUTION */

#text-container, #btn-container {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
}

#text-container {
    width: 70%;     
}

#btn-container {
    width: 28%;  
}

#btn-container .ui-btn {
    margin-top: -9px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

You only need to take care about button width, this example is made to accommodate your current button. In any other case modify first and second css style width.

Second solution is probably the best one.

Comment: The gap between the input box and button is due to the usage of "fieldcontain"

Answer (score 3):

Here is another example using `grids`. Grids are useful for such cases as they responsive. You dont have to worry when orientation changes.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Bkvh8/)

Markup

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
 <div class="ui-block-a">
  <input type="text" name="" value="" />
 </div>
 <div class="ui-block-b">
    <button type="reset" data-theme="b">Reset</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ui-block-b {
 width: 25% !important;
}
.ui-block-a {
 width: 75% !important;
 padding-top: 3px !important; // to push down input box.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your update working correctly then it seem `data-inline="true"` attribute is not possible for this scenario

Comment: @FazlulRahman `data-inline` works for buttons but not for text input. the idea of it is to utilize the available width when it `true` or set width according to button's text.

Answer (score 1):

### update

You can't mix up buttons and text input in the same line using data-inline attribute.

Instead [use Grids](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/grids/).

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="text" name="name" data-inline="true" id="basic" value=""  /> </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b" align="right"><button type="reset" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Reset</button></div>
</div>
```

Live fiddle example available at http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/ewaBd/1/

### old answer

```
<button type="submit" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Save</button> 
<button type="submit" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Rest</button>
```

Its just working fine.

Check out this <kbd>**[Live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/BFWvG/)**</kbd> http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/BFWvG/

Comment: `data-inline="true"` is applicable only for buttons. You can't mix up buttons with other elements. Think of using grids in your case.

Comment: Thank you for this, but grids are in this case not favorable because it doesn't keep the two element closer except inlining.

Answer (score 0):

the style is working fine; check the @MayuMayooresan 's fiddle, but if you want to href is working to; do it like this:

```
<a href="index.html"><button type="submit" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Save</button></a>
```

look: http://jsfiddle.net/BFWvG/3/

Comment: do you mean you want to the input and button in same line?

Comment: this fiddle is not answer to the question